# Timer method in Background thread iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I want to run timer for 20 minutes wether my app is in backgroud or foreground that timer should be continued till 20 minutes.
Any one know how to manage this?
Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already try something?

Comment: check my answer at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478287/how-to-maintain-timer-to-continue-running-when-home-button-is-pressed/40479522#40479522

Comment: Essentially, you can't.