# UILocalNotification is Not Working When app goes in background or simulator goes lock

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have Made one  UILocalNotification Base demo.
When My app goes background or my simulator goes lock it will fire notification.
But It is not working can any one tell me?

## Code is

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSDate *todayDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:5.0];
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    if(notification)
    {
        notification.fireDate = todayDate;
        notification.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notification.repeatInterval = 0;
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notification.alertBody = @"Yor Are Working On Push Notification";
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

    }
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    UIApplication *app  =[UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *oldNotification = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
    if([oldNotification count ] >0)
    {
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
}
```

I am new in new in ios ,let me inform if i did mistake.Or please give me suggested link for specific answer.
Thank You

Comment: you can get some idea through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478287/how-to-maintain-timer-to-continue-running-when-home-button-is-pressed/40479522#40479522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifire = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifire];
    }];

    [self scheduleNotification];
}

- (void)scheduleNotification {
    UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Title" arguments:nil];
    content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Yor Are Working On Push Notification" arguments:nil];

    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:NO];
    UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"notification" content:content trigger:trigger];
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:nil];
}
```